AM-GM inequality (but equality cannot be attained)

Let $a+b+c=1$ with $a,b,c$ positive reals. Prove that $ab^2c^3\le 108$.

One could apply the AM-GM inequality here, as follows: $$1=a+b+c=a+\frac{b}{2}+\frac{b}{2}+\frac{c}{3}+\frac{c}{3}+\frac{c}{3}\ge\sqrt[6]{ab^2c^3/108},$$
which rearranges to $ab^2c^3\le 108$ as required.
However, since $a,b,c$ are positive reals which sum to $1$, each of $a,b,c$ is between $0$ and $1$. Therefore it is surely impossible for the product to exceed $1$, let alone $108$?

Yes, you are right. In fact, you can use the Lagrange multiplier method to find the maximum

@K.Jiang AM-GM assumes they are nonnegative reals though; why does the method not work?

@math... lagrange multipliers is such a long method!!

Personally, I think it is fine. Notice that the constrains are linear, so you will get a constant when you take the partial derivative. So you get $q_i(a,b,c)=k$ for some function $q_i$ and constant $k$, then solve for $a,b,c$. However for this question, I would prefer AM-GM, because it is simpler.

I get a max of $1/432$ what is for sure $\le 108$ me think.

@K.Jiang You need the numbers to be non-negative.  Otherwise try for e.g. $a=-10, c=-10, b=21$ and see what happens even though $ab^2c^3>0$.

You can try Weighted AM-GM

You did not apply AGM correctly. One has
$$
\frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}n\ge\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n}.
$$
So you are missing a factor 6,
$$
\frac16\ge\sqrt[6]{ab^2c^3/108}\iff ab^2c^3\le \frac{108}{6^6}=\frac1{432},
$$
This small bound should be more in line with the expectations.

Beat me to it +1. I simplified the true bound to a simple fraction. Note that the calculation is simplified by the exponents being the proper divisors of a perfect number.

A properly constructed AM-GM bound is always sharp. But we have to be careful how to construct this bound.
Given the problem
$a+b+c=1; a,b,c>0; \text{ maximize }ab^2c^3$
we first render
$1=a+b+c=\color{blue}{1}a+\color{blue}{2}(\frac12b)+\color{blue}{3}(\frac13c)\tag{1}$
The blue coefficients match the exponents in the objective function, and then of course we must multiply the variables in the sum by the reciprocals of these exponents to compensate.
We then multiply (1) by the sum of the coefficients/exponents and place the result over a denominator equal to this sum to get the arithmetic mean:
$1=\dfrac{1(6a)+2(3b)+3(2c)}6$
The corresponding geometric mean is then
$\sqrt[6]{(6a)^1(3b)^2(2c)^3}\le1\implies ab^2c^3\le\dfrac1{432},$
as was also found by Lutz Lehman. This is the sharp bound, saturated at $6a=3b=2c\implies a=\frac16,b=\frac13,c=\frac12$.

A very clear explanation!
